# How to connect two users in one room in React Native JSX

Tags: react-native, authentication, chat, jsx

i am a newbie. Making my first app in react-native. I am stuck on one step.

In the app a user can create a room on regestration. The room is shared ONLY between 2 users. So the second user can connect to it using the name of  the room and the password. Both users won't share one screen. The connection between the users in the room will be used only at the end. When the "game" is finished, the second user will be notified and will get a list of tasks that the first user has completed.

How could i achieve it?

THanks for any help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not help you. The questions in stackoverflow must be specific in a specific topic or an error, I invite you to reformulate your question

Comment: Hi @FrFernandez. How should i do it? just edit my text or to rite a new question? It is just seems that i cannot give any more information due to the fact that i am new to this. I dotn even know should i use Firebase or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `firebase` or if you want to maintain, you can write a socket server using `socket.io`. If you're building using socket.io, then you can create a room when users join and send messages between users when you want to.

Comment: Thaks for your reply. As i mentioned to the other guy, i have studied the socket.io today and managed to create a small separate app to check my understanding. so fart it works with a single room. So my question is, do i need too use some kind of a database storage like MongoDB to be able to use a set of separate rooms and users??

Comment: You don't need any DB to setup rooms using socket.io. you just need to use `join('testing')` method to join a socket connection to a room called. You can connect as many users as you want into a room and maintain as many separate rooms that you can name of as mentioned in the docs
https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Joining-and-leaving

Comment: Okay, i got that. But at what point should the user be able to generate a room. Shold it be in my server( backend ) js where the io.on is located ?

Comment: That depends on your application logic. It can either come from a user (chat rooms scenarion where user enters room name) or your server can generate random room names. Finally everyone who's joining the room should use the same room name.

Comment: Right so i get this aprt as well. Also i understood taht each room has its specific id created. The second case that u described is closer to my app. However i got one more question then. So, the user onPress will join to the pre-created room randomly. I would like to allocate a password to every single room. So that the next user will have to user the password to connect to the first user. How could i achieve that in socket.io? BTW thanks a lot for your help, i already start understating much more thanks to you !

Comment: It's good to hear that you're understanding. Please try to do it by yourself and raise a different question with any specific issues that you're facing with your code implementing it. For future reference please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you learn the fundamentals of SocketIO, Websockets, Node.JS.

Follow a tutorial on building a real time chat app. SocketIO has a rooms API you can use to join users to share data in real time.

Comment: Hi Alim. I have learned a bit and made a small structure i.e. separate app to check my knowledge. It works for one person and one more. Do i have to use some kind of a database to allow working with a set of rooms? for example MongoDB ??